# How to disable all products from specific category?

Tags: product, ce-1.7.0.2, catalog

I am using CE 1.7.0.2, I want to disable all products from one specific category.

How I can disable all products from category? (SQL is fine)

Comment: can you please tell me? if a product  would also included in other categories then what would be happen

Comment: if product is in another category as well even then product should be disable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new file in in your Magento root, call it `products-disable.php` and paste in the following

```
    <?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $categoryId = 123;
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

    if ($category->getId()) {
        $products = $category->getProductCollection();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product->setData('status', false);
            $product->save();
        }
    } else {
        die("category failed to load");
    }
```

Then browse to your site `http://mymagesite.url/products-disable.php` and it should set the status of all the products in that category as `false`

DONT RUN THIS STRAIGHT ON YOUR PRODUCTION SITE. Test it out first :)

edit :

This magento code will update your database as a bulk action, so far quicker than the initial save on each row. I've batched it in pages of `500`, change that value in the `setPageSize` call to whatever you please. I'd recommend this method FAR more than doing a direct sql change as it will trigger events and indexes and stuff.

I haven't tested this code, but believe it should work.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$categoryId = 123;
$storeCode = 'default';

$storeId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeCode)->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

if ($storeId && $category->getId()) {

    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns('entity_id');

    $collection->setPageSize(500);

    for ($curPage = 1; $curPage <= $collection->getLastPageNumber(); $curPage++) {
        $collection->clear();
        $collection->setCurPage($curPage);

        $ids = array();
        foreach ($collection as $_product) {
            $ids[$_product->getId()] = $_product->getId();
        }

        if (!empty($ids)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($ids, array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED), $storeId);
        }
    }

} else {
    die("category or store failed to load");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke. Is there any way we can do it using SQL? As I have more than 50000 products in one category.

Comment: Gotcha, give me 5 mins :)

Comment: See my edit for updated code

Comment: For example category has 2000 products. How I can disable all products in this category using your script?

Comment: BTW script throw error at line 25

Comment: haha! change that $product to be $_product

Comment: Second approach much better than the first one. +1

Comment: what is exactly setPageSize means?

Comment: still not working...

Comment: My mistake, I assumed setting status to false would be disabled. Turns out Magento has that constant pointing to '2' instead of something that resolves to false! I've updated the code. If it's still not working, try adding `print_r($ids);` before the `if (!empty($ids)) {` call

Comment: Script show correct ids by `print_r($ids);` but Nope still all products are enabled even after reindexing

Comment: Did you change the updateAttributes call to use `array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED` ? Are you in using the correct store code / viewing the correct store scope in the admin panel?

Comment: If I tried your first script with `$product->setData('status', '2');` then status change to `disabled` but its not working with second script. I tried as you said in last comment.

Comment: I just tried           `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array('22345'), array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED), Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);` on my local machine and it correctly disabled the product in the admin scope. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: Yeah its worked. Just tell me For example category has 2000 products. How I can disable all products in this category using `setPageSize` variable batch value of 500?

Comment: Look at the second code sample, particularly the lines surrounding `$collection->clear();`. These lines will iterate over a collection of any size, 2000000 if needed, but only loading `500` products at a time. PageSize = 500, CurPage = 2 would be displaying products 500 to 1000. PageSize = 500, CurPage = 3 would be displaying products 1000 to 1500. See?

Comment: If this has been helpful please mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this which is give you list  of products  specifiv cat

**For getting this category products:**

```
SELECT `e`.`value_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `e` 
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `cp` ON e.entity_id = cp.product_id WHERE (cp.category_id IN(15)) and e.attribute_id = 96 )
```

**and disable the product by**

```
update  `catalog_product_entity_int` set  `catalog_product_entity_int`.value_id =0 where `catalog_product_entity_int`.`value_id` in (YOUR_UPPer_value_Ids)
```

Where 15 in `category ids`

Comment: what is product.attribute_id?

Comment: I believe thats the default magento attr id for "status". It's unlikely that it's different on your instance, but it is possible! This is why I prefer the direct Magento approach, works on all systems. `select attribute_id, attribute_code,source_model from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='status';` shows `96` as the attribute_id on my instance

Answer (score 0):

**FOR MAGENTO 2**
Disable All products from a specific category.

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_product` JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` ON catalog_category_product.product_id = catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id SET catalog_product_entity_int.value = 2 WHERE catalog_category_product.category_id=1754 AND catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id = 94
```

Run This query.

- attribute id 94 taken from eav_attribute table. i.e enable/disable field of product
- Category id has taken static because I want to update from this category.
- value=2 means disable the product

So this query is taking all products from catalog_category_product.product_id WHERE category_id= 1754. And then matching product id and entity id in catalog_product_entity_int and updating value in catalog_product_entity_int.value column as disable i.e 2